# Module not found on Ubuntu

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm having trouble importing Quill in my Angular2 app. (2.0.1)

I have added `"quill": "^1.0.4"` and `"@types/quill": "*",` to my package.json, and ind the component I'm using it in I have imported it in the top :

```
import * as Quill from 'Quill';
```

and defined it as

```
let quill = new Quill('#editor', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
      },
      theme: 'snow'
    });
```

On my Mac, running macOS Sierra, there aren no problems, but on a Ubuntu machine I'll get the following error

```
ng/src/community/threads.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'Quill' in /home/user/src/community
 @ ./src/community/threads.component.ts 16:12-28
Warning: Task "webpack:default" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Anybody able to help? I've tried loading the git repo on another Mac, installing the latest Node, Npm and grunt-cli and again there are no problems.

Comment: Hi @catu, did you found a solution?

Comment: No, we ended up using TinyMCE in stead.